# Rotational invariance of Particle in constant magnetic field in $2D$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry

Consider a particle in two dimensions with an external magnetic field in the z-direction. The vector potential can be chosen to be $\mathbf{A}=-By\ \hat{x}$ so that the Hamiltonian given by
$$H=\frac{(p_x+eBy)^2}{2m}+\frac{p_y^2}{2m}$$
I'm trying to prove that the system has rotational symmetry. This makes sense since you have a constant field in $z$-direction and the rotating thing will not change anything. To see prove this, We need to prove that
$$[H,L_z]=0$$
To find out, first, we can break $H$ as
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{(eB)^2}{2m}y^2+\frac{eB}{m}yp_x$$

It's easy to show with little algebra that
$$[H,L_z]\not = 0$$
I am not able to understand, Why this is so? Is it because of choosing some specific gauge? How we can show that this problem has a rotational symmetry?

Comment: This gauge breaks the rotational symmetry. Choose a different gauge $A_x=-By/2, A_y=Bx/2$, the rotation symmetry is restored.

Comment: @MengCheng I got it,  I have a follow-up, what about translation symmetry? System should have, but I'm not able to show that in either gauge.

Comment: You need to modify the translation operator to account for the change in $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: http://bingweb.binghamton.edu/~suzuki/QuantumMechanicsII/14-5_Landau_level.pdf this note should answer all of your questions.